# JS function is returning Javascript to browser instead of expected Ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax

I swear this used to work. I am trying to do breadcrumbs. I have a JS function in the global namespace called "breadcrumb". It accepts a string as its only parameter:

```
function breadcrumb(attr) {
  hash = { type: "POST", url: "brands/get_attributes", data: $("#attributeform").serialize() };
  $.ajax(hash);
  return false;
}
```

I have my breadcrumb link on the HTML page defined as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:breadcrumb(\'<%= brand_attribute.attributename %>\');"><%= value %></a>
```

Fine so far. But when I click the breadcrumb link, I get this in the URL:

```
javascript:breadcrumb('Whirlpool');
```

And a blank page with the word "false", which is what the function returns. My question is, why is it actually navigating to the javascript function itself? Why is the Ajax result not being rendered?

Comment: No way you can bind the click event, instead of inline javascript?

Comment: Chad, I did what you said, and ended up putting the param in an attribute of the link. It works! Please put an answer in so that I can award you (and keep my 100% answer rating) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onclick rather than href.  Also, the OCD in me suggests the following syntax change:

```
var hash = { //use braces to define an object
               type: "POST", 
               url: "brands/get_attributes", 
               data: $("#attributeform").serialize()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `href` to `onclick`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return breadcrumb(\'<%= brand_attribute.attributename %>\');"><%= value %></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your <a> tag's href doesn't contain a void(0); statement at the end, so the value of your breadcrumb function is returned to the browser.

Try changing:

```
href="javascript:breadcrumb(\'<%= brand_attribute.attributename %>\');"
```

to:

```
href="javascript:breadcrumb(\'<%= brand_attribute.attributename %>\');void(0);"
```

edit: I would also agree with jakubka's answer, it would be better practice to keep javascript calls in the onclick attributes of your links as opposed to the href.

So,

```
href="#" onclick="breadcrumb(\'<%= brand_attribute.attributename %>\');"
```